# Many to Many table collection_select error

Tags: many-to-many, has-many-through, nested-form-for

I am trying to have rails populate an inbetween table.  The inbetween table is: room_task
The form I am using is the new task form, which is nested.

Here is the model:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base (property is parent nest)
  attr_accessible   :brand_id, :name, :user_property_code, :total_rooms, :property_addresses_attributes
  belongs_to :brand
  has_many :rooms
  has_many :nonrooms
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base (room)
  attr_accessible :number, :out_of_order, :property_id, :room_type_id, :taskable_id
  belongs_to :room_type
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :room_tasks
  has_many :tasks, through: :room_tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :room_tasks
  #add_index :room, :property_id
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base (task)
  attr_accessible :number, :out_of_order, :property_id, :room_type_id, :taskable_id
  belongs_to :room_type
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :room_tasks
  has_many :tasks, through: :room_tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :room_tasks
  #add_index :room, :property_id
end

class RoomTask < ActiveRecord::Base (in between table)
  attr_accessible :room_id, :task_id

  has_one :room
  has_one :task
  belongs_to :room # foreign key - room id
  belongs_to :task # foreign key - task id
end
```

Controller (task - where I want to create the new task and also the required relationship in the inbetween table)

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_property

  def find_property
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    @room = @property.rooms
  end


  # GET /tasks
  # GET /tasks.json
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @tasks }
    end
  end

  # GET /tasks/1
  # GET /tasks/1.json
  def show
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @task }
    end
  end

  # GET /tasks/new
  # GET /tasks/new.json
  def new
    @task = Task.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @task }
    end
  end

  # GET /tasks/1/edit
  def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /tasks
  # POST /tasks.json
  def create
    @task = Task.new(params[:task])

    @task.time_assigned = Time.now
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save

        format.html { redirect_to property_tasks_path(@property), notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /tasks/1
  # PUT /tasks/1.json
  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tasks/1
  # DELETE /tasks/1.json
  def destroy
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tasks_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Form (using a collection select (purpose would be to select the room of the property that the task is tied to and populate in the inbetween table)

```
<%= form_for([@property, @task]) do |f| %>
  <% if @task.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@task.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this task from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <%= fields_for(:room_task) do |t| %>
    <%= collection_select(:room_task, :room_id, @room, :id, :number) %> #without t. works but does not assign
    <% end %>



    <%= @room %> #debug collection pull - good

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So I need help on ensuring that my inbetween table is populated when selecting the room.  When f. or t. is prefixed to the collection_select, rails throws errors.
I am extremely confused.  Help would be greatly appreciated, please let me know if any additional information is needed.

receiving this error when adding f. or t.

undefined method `merge' for :number:Symbol

displays and works fine without f. or t. but does not populate table.